# Correlation between momentum and displacement thickness

Tags: aerodynamics

I'm new to the problem of boundary layers, and came across the following task:

> Let us consider a stationary incompressible laminar flow around a flat plate at zero angle of attack. The coordinate x = 0 corresponds to the leading edge. What is the momentum thickness at x = 0.9m if the displacement thickness at x = 0.1m is 2mm?

The formulas for displacement thickness  and momentum thickness are respectively given as:

$\delta_*=\int_0^\infty [1-\cfrac{u(x,y)}{U(x)}] \,dy$, $\theta=\int_0^\infty \cfrac{u(x,y)}{U(x)}[1-\cfrac{u(x,y)}{U(x)}] \,dy$

How do I tackle this tasj without the distribution of speed? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As they've given you no information other than the boundary layer is laminar, I think it's fair to assume a velocity profile given by the Blasius solution. The Wikipedia page gives expressions for the displacement and momentum thickness you can use.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blasius_boundary_layer